# Как связать данные и интерфейс с помощью Binding в WPF

Tags: wpf, .net, xaml

Как связать значение переменой, которая хранится внутри класса `MyClass`, с элементом в интерфейсе (переменная  *int*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML

```
<Border Padding="{Binding Padding}">
```

C#

```
private int _Padding;
public int Padding
{
    get
    {
        return _Padding;
    }
    set 
    {
        _Padding = value; 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Padding");
    }
}
```

При этом DataContext в XAML должен быть установлен на класс, свойством которого является Padding. А класс должен реализовывать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Также отмечу, что существует другой способ: если класс с необходимыми данными наследуется от `DependencyObject`, то можно привязать свойство, если оно реализовано как `DependencyProperty` (в таком случае класс не обязан реализовывать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Да, этот способ самы распространенный и понятный. Но существует еще куча способов, начиная с объявления класса со свойством в ресурсах, использования шаблонов, создания привязки программно (тогда, кстати, источник можно указать явно, без привязки к контексту) и т.п. Правильный выбор можно сделать только зная задачу целиком.

Comment: Думаю оставлюсь на первом варианте.

Я только начал учить  WPF , и не принципиально на данном этапа как реализовать эту задачу.

Спасибо всем